# Queueing in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".menu .menu-item-has-children .dropdown-arrow").click(function() {

  $(this).parent().toggleClass('have-submenu-opened');

  $('.menu').find('.have-submenu-opened').find('.sub-menu.display-on').removeClass('display-on');

        $(this).parent().find(".sub-menu").toggleClass("display-on");
    });
```

I have to be sure that:
    `$(this).parent().toggleClass('have-submenu-opened');`
will run and be completed before:
 `$(this).parent().find(".sub-menu").toggleClass("display-on");`

Comment: You should use promise

Comment: Is that not already the case?  `toggleClass()` isn't doing anything asynchronous.  It should be completing pretty much right away.  Are you observing something different?

Answer (score 0):

See [JQuery when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

```
$.when(firstFunction)
 .then(secondFunction, myFailure );
```